# Firebase Recycler Adapter Querying database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to retrieve specific data from firebase real time database. I know complex querying of firebase database is not possible.

[image: Database Image snapshot]

Here is my database snapshot, what I want to do is first order my database with count so I used query .orderByChild("count") and passed it to Recycler option. OK that's fine. But now additionally what I want is  the data should be displayed if an if only if recommendation = recommended. i.e. double query.

I think we cant use double query in real time database so what I did was....

```
/*
condition =
  recyclerView = Linearlayout manager
  setQuery = orderbychild count
*/

  //actual logic for hiding non required data

        if (model.getRecommendation().equals("recommended")) {

            holder.recommendationLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else {

            holder.hideView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.hideView.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
            holder.hideView.getLayoutParams().width = 0;

            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams =
            (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.hideView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

            holder.hideView.requestLayout();
       }
```

[image: Product layout sorted]

But when I change my layout manager to **GridLayoutManager**

[image: Grid layout manager]

Sadly it keeps white space wherever the product tag is not recommended

So my question is how can we avoid this white space or is there any method I can sort my database and pass double query or whatever ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change layout_width = wrap_content of your root layout for your list item..
2. Pass your array list

`Collections.sort(itemsLists);`

Then on your model class add a compareTo method...
Refer here :- https://howtodoinjava.com/sort/collections-sort/